# Will it be $\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}$ or $\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}$?

Tags: vectors, mathematics, geometry

[image]

The resultant of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ is $\vec{AD}$. Now, which of the following is correct?

$$\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}\tag{1}$$

$$\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}\tag{2}$$

I think $(1)$ is correct.

Comment: Crossposted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4410932/768162)

Comment: Are you assuming $|\vec{DB}| = |\vec{AC}|$?

Comment: @Mauricio Yes, I am assuming that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) is correct, the resultant means the addition

Answer (score 3):

For the given drawing $\vec{AD}$ vector CAN NOT be $\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}$.

Realize that $\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}$ can be written as $\vec{AB}+(-\vec{AC})$ and that a minus sign in front of a vector flips its direction.

In your drawing $\vec{AC}$ is to the left. Therefore $-\vec{AC}$ must be to the right. You can not add two vectors both to the right and get a resultant vector which is shorter than the original vectors.

So correct answer must be  $\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}$.

Answer (score 2):

In your diagram you have drawn arrows which show that $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are opposite in direction. Hence you need not add an additional negative sign. Hence (1) is correct.
However, if you want to write it in terms of magnitudes,
$|\vec{AB}|−|\vec{AC}|=|\vec{AD}|$
would be the right way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\hat \imath$ be the unit vector pointing to the right.

$\vec {AB} = AB \,\hat \imath$ and $\vec {AC} = AC \,(-\hat \imath)$ where $AB$ and $AC$ are the magnitudes of the two vectors.

$\vec {AB} + \vec {AC} = AB \,\hat \imath+AC \,(-\hat \imath) = (AB-AC)\,\hat \imath = AD\,\hat \imath = \vec {AD}$ where $AD$ is the magnitude of $\vec {AD}$.

Comment: You might want to consider using `\hat{\imath}` instead of `\hat{i}`. It removes the dot and is specifically designed for these things. Similarly, there is also `\jmath`.

Comment: Thanks.  "One lives and learns" but my problem is "will I remember?"  :-)

Comment: As usual, why -1?